# MVC5 - Passing var not in form from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I get the following error message:

> UploadId is a nullable value error

I am assuming it may be related to the data table I am using. For the controller I take in form collection form and int `UploadId`:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data;

@using (Html.BeginForm("myfunc", "Index", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}, new { UploadId = @ViewBag.UploadId }))
{
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult myfunc(FormCollection form)
    {
        var theUploadId = form.UploadId;
        return RedirectToAction("Send", "Mail", new { theUploadId = theUploadId });
    }
```

Comment: Your `BeginForm()` is not even valid (there is no overload that accepts 6 parameters). Its `@using (Html.BeginForm("myfunc", "Index", new { UploadId = @ViewBag.UploadId }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"})` and the method would be `public ActionResult myfunc(int UploadId)`

Answer (score 0):

when you use `@ViewBag.UploadId` in your view then you need to use the exact name when you pass it from you controller.
Try using the following in your controller method:

```
return RedirectToAction("Send", "Mail", new { UploadId = theUploadId });
```